# Php tries to allocate unnecessary memory (hundreds MB free, allocates more than allowed, throwing an 'Allowed memory size' error) (PHP7)

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, php-7

I've got a PHP script I run from a cron task. I'ts something like this

```
<?php

require_once 'script1.php';
// Here I do a lot of SQL querys, and my memory usage and allocated memory goes up
// then I set all the variables to null and unset them to free memory
gc_collect_cycles(); // I added this to try to force freeing memory

require_once 'script2.php';
// Here I do a lot of SQL querys, and my allocated memory goes up again ...
gc_collect_cycles(); // I added this to try to force freeing memory

require_once 'script3.php';
// And Here when I do one big query it throws me the 'Allowed memory size' error.
```

These are dumps of the memory, made with..

```
MEM=memory_get_usage(false)
MEMR=memory_get_usage(true)
MEMpeak=memory_get_peak_usage(false)
MEMRpeak=memory_get_peak_usage(true)
```

1) After script 1:

```
MEM 5.9628219604492 MEMR 244 MEMpeak 243.41315460205 MEMRpeak 248.5
```

2) After script 2:

```
MEM 7.9203491210938 MEMR 244 MEMpeak 243.41315460205 MEMRpeak 251.34765625`
```

3) before script 3:

```
MEM 7.8667755126953 MEMR 244 MEMpeak 243.41315460205 MEMRpeak 251.34765625
```

4) on script 3, the line before I do a 'mysqli_query(...':

```
MEM 9.0010223388672 MEMR 244 MEMpeak 243.419090271 MEMRpeak 251.34765625
```

And then I get the error:
PHP Fatal error:  `Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19552176 bytes) in ...`

However if I increase the memory limite to 512M, I get this memory dump after the line that previously crashed:

```
MEM 35.54125213623 MEMR 266.6484375 MEMpeak 243.419090271 MEMRpeak 266.6484375
```

I don't understand what's happening: at the begging of script 3 I had 243MB of allocated memory and 9MB of used memory (so I still have 234 MB of free allocated memory, right?).

Then PHP tries to allocate 22MB more of memory, (having to save 29MB more of data on memory).

Why is not using the free allocated memory?

EDIT: These are me readings when I run script 3 alone:

- start:

  `MEM 5.83447265625 MEMR 8 MEMpeak 6.7176361083984 MEMRpeak 8`
- end (before setting all vars to null):

  `MEM 57.858413696289 MEMR 90.25 MEMpeak 107.6799621582 MEMRpeak 108.8984375`
- end (after setting all vars to null):

  `MEM 6.9840774536133 MEMR 88 MEMpeak 107.6799621582 MEMRpeak 108.8984375`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fetch row by row insead of fetch all.

Comment: The error I get is when I do  a mysqli_query.
However, I'm already fetching row by row using mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: Only one thing i can imagine - too much data from db and mysqli driver can't allocate memory for that.
After execute query all data store in process pool and mysqli_fetch_array only iterate it.